# Android Intent for standard operations, specifically Application Launcher

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'd like to add a button to my app that will show the list of applications.  I cannot seem to determine the correct Intent.  I've been trying ACTION_ALL_APPS, but I get ActivityNotFound exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard activity that displays all applications. You need to retrieve a list of all applications and display it in your own list. You can retrieve all the applications with this code snippet

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> riList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Hmm.. well i had started to write my own using the same calls you suggest, but i thought it would be faster to reuse.  If you what you suggest is true, and you cannot call the intent that the default OS uses to display the list of applications, does anyone know what the ACTION_ALL_APPS is used for then?

Comment: The launcher does not use an Intent to display the applications list.  The ACTION_ALL_APPS is not used and should probably be removed.

Comment: Thanks.  I've moved on to create my own activity which lists the apps using the info provided.